# Air Printing crash on ipad

Tags: ipad, printing, crash

I am having a trouble with printing on ipad. My code prints the pdf file perfectly for the first time; but when I print my pdf file for the second time the app freezes and then crashes.

```
Below is my code:
    NSData *myPdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pdfPath]; 
    UIPrintInteractionController *controller = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
    if (controller && [UIPrintInteractionController canPrintData:myPdfData]){
        controller.delegate = delegate;
        UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo]; 
        printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral; 
        printInfo.jobName = [pdfPath lastPathComponent];    
        printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge; 
        controller.printInfo = printInfo;
        controller.showsPageRange = YES;
        controller.printingItem = myPdfData;    

        // We need a completion handler block for printing.
        UIPrintInteractionCompletionHandler completionHandler = ^(UIPrintInteractionController *printController, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
            if(completed && error){
                NSLog(@"FAILED! due to error in domain %@ with error code %u", error.domain, error.code);
            }
        };

        [controller presentFromRect:[sender frame] inView:senderView animated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
    }else {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't get shared UIPrintInteractionController!");
    }
```

Below is my stack trace from the device:

D

```
ate/Time:       2011-03-17 20:48:02.523 -0700
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.3 (8F190)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x8badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
Brighton failed to resume in time

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 2.310 (user 0.290, system 2.020), 23% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.000, 0% CPU

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x30bd2ab0 0x30bc2000 + 68272
1   PrintKit                        0x313f2c1a 0x313df000 + 80922
2   PrintKit                        0x313ee9ea 0x313df000 + 63978
3   PrintKit                        0x313eea90 0x313df000 + 64144
4   PrintKit                        0x313eeab4 0x313df000 + 64180
5   PrintKit                        0x313e4f96 0x313df000 + 24470
6   PrintKit                        0x313e266a 0x313df000 + 13930
7   UIKit                           0x335e3656 0x33311000 + 2958934
8   UIKit                           0x335e904c 0x33311000 + 2981964
9   UIKit                           0x335e8bcc 0x33311000 + 2980812
10  UIKit                           0x335e99fc 0x33311000 + 2984444
11  UIKit                           0x3343460c 0x33311000 + 1193484
12  Foundation                      0x30d306ce 0x30cab000 + 546510
13  CoreFoundation                  0x31c43a40 0x31bce000 + 481856
14  CoreFoundation                  0x31c45ec4 0x31bce000 + 491204
15  CoreFoundation                  0x31c4683e 0x31bce000 + 493630
16  CoreFoundation                  0x31bd6ebc 0x31bce000 + 36540
17  CoreFoundation                  0x31bd6dc4 0x31bce000 + 36292
18  GraphicsServices                0x32dbf418 0x32dbb000 + 17432
19  GraphicsServices                0x32dbf4c4 0x32dbb000 + 17604
```

It would be really helpful if anyone could help me figure out the issue.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clue is in this: "Brighton failed to resume in time."

When printing is finished, control is returned to your app but you take too long to respond. iOS thinks that you've stopped responding to input and kills your app.